# Negate expression containing && operator

Tags: c++, loops, operators

I was making a slot machine that loops until all three `std::string`s have the **same value**. I'm confused as to why in this code the `|| operator` is giving the desired result rather than the `&& operator`.

```
std::string slotA,slotB,slotC; 
do {
    //Fill slotA, slotB and slotC with some data
} while (slotB != slotC || slotB != slotA);
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your stop condition should be:

```
while (!(slotB == slotC && slotB == slotA));
```

However, in Bool-Algebra `!(slotB == slotC && slotB == slotA)` is equal to `slotB != slotC || slotB != slotA`

This rule is called [De Morgan Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution and for the rule :)

Comment: It's worth noting that C and C++ do not support shared arguments to comparison operators, as in mathematical notation. E.g. `slotA == slotB == slotC` will compile (possibly with a warning), but yielding an incorrect result since it's parsed as `(slotA == slotB) == slotC`. However, Python supports that notation. So this is one gotcha for new C++ programmers coming from Python.

Answer (score 4):

`(slotB != slotC || slotB != slotA)` Is the good way to do your work.

A little example if you use :

```
(slotB != slotC && slotB != slotA)
```

usuming :

```
slotA = Banana
slotB = Banana
slotC = Apple
```

so :

```
(slotB  != slotC && slotB  != slotA)
(Banana != Apple && Banana != Banana)
( true && false)
( false )
```

The while loop end with a bad guesses.

In your case it's maybe more simple to write the condition for a good guesses and
take the negative, like Humam Helfawi says :

```
 while (!(slotB == slotC && slotB == slotA))
```

Answer (score 2):

I think there is possibility that two strings are same and third one different which might make you loop condition fail if you use &&(and) operator.

i.e. `slotA` and `slotB` might me equal which makes `slotA != slotB` a false statement and it will come out of the loop. but when you use `||` condition the `slotC != slotB` is true and it continues the loop.

Note: This is one of the possibility but might not be the actual reason.